# SQL Average calculation

Tags: sql

Let's say there is an employer entity and it has an attribute of salary. And employer works in a department which is located in Oxford Building.(Building address is unique for building)

How can I write a SQL query that computes the average salary per building? Does it mean that salary is foreign key or what? Is it correct, if I do just

```
SELECT AVG(Salary) AS Averagesalary FROM Employee;
```

but in that case there will be no Building

Answer (score 3):

That's why there's `GROUP BY`, to specify how you want to "group" your records. Right now you're doing an average of ALL records in table.

```
SELECT Building, AVG(SALARY)
FROM Employee
GROUP BY Building
```

The above query will also average all records, but do it per-building.